Creation of conda on mounted drive results in: Function not implemented: 'cacert.pem' -> '/mnt/path/to/condaEnv/ssl/cert.pem
Does someone know how to resolve:
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(949): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::ca-certificates-2024.2.2-hbcca054_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 38] Function not implemented: 'cacert.pem' -> '/mnt/drive/condaEnv/ssl/cert.pem'
()

It works if I create a conda environment in my ~/paths/ but not on my other drive.
Thanks for any help.
